# How to open file after each published application

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, version

I want to open a HTML file from my project after each application downloaded new version. So for example when I open application and new version is available and I update it I want to open an HTML file. But only for the first time. Only once after each new version.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Check the modified time, store it somewhere, check if it has changed next time.

Answer (score 0):

To open a URL in the default browser:

```
string myUri = "http://stackoverflow.com";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(myUri);
```

Without seeing the rest of your code, I can't give you any more tips